# Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with corners (periodic tridiagonal, cyclic tridiagonal)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, minimal-polynomials, tridiagonal-matrices

I have conjectured that the eigenvalues of the following $N\times N$ matrix are all distinct:

$$\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi 0}{N}  \right)&-\frac{1}{2}&&&&&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\sin\left(\frac{2\pi 1}{N}  \right)&-\frac{1}{2}&&&&\\
&\frac{1}{2}&\sin\left(\frac{2\pi 2}{N}  \right)&\ddots&&&\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&\\
&&&\ddots&\ddots&-\frac{1}{2}&\\
&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (N-2)}{N}  \right)&-\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}  \right)
\end{array}\right].$$
Can anyone help me in providing a proof regarding this fact?

The omitted components of $A$ are all zero.

Comment: Hint: induction on the size of the matrix. Expand the determinant using the first column, say.